# How to create an expression where variable "$x$" is always divisible by static value "$a$"

Tags: functions, algorithms

So I'm trying to figure out a way to make an equation where, for example, $a=2$

$x$ is an integer, $a=2\implies x=\{\cdots ,-4,-2,0,2,4,\cdots\}$

I know that I could do it by using the modulo statement, but I can't figure out a way to make it by raw mathematical equation or adding another variable that is also stated to be an integer

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand what it is you want here. The usual notation for asserting that $x$ is divisible by $a$ is "$a\mid x$" -- if that is not what you want, then what does it lack that you need? Does "raw mathematical equation" have a specific meaning to you here? You'll probably need to explain what that meaning is; it is not a standard technical term.

Comment: How about $at=x$ where $t\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: So you don't want to introduce another variable? Because otherwise you can do as kingW3 has stated above. Otherwise the only other way is what Henning has said.

Comment: I think the king has cracked this one.

Comment: What on earth is the sentence "a is two $x$ is an integer, $a$ is $2$ $=>$ $x=${$...-4,-2,0,2,4,...$}" supposed to mean?

Comment: Ehm, sorry - I guess I was tad unclear. Here's a live example of the same principle, but a completely different requirement:

The group of x in $x^3+10x^2+9x=0$ is {$-9, -3, 0$}

How could I make a notation for the group {$...,-4, -2,0,2,4,...$} on terms of $x∈Z$, so that $x=P$ where P always gives an answer dividable by the number two, without adding new variables.